# Can't read files correctly

Tags: python

I'm trying to split my dataset into test train and validation. I'm going by a book I read and i get an error using the book syntax. I tried replacing the '/' with '\' and even with '\' but I can't solve the problem.
Code:

```
# --> Listing 5.4 Copying Images to training, validation and test direcotries
import os, shutil

# Path to the directory where the original DS was uncompressed

original_dir = 'datasets/catsvdogs'

# Directory to store my smaller dataset

base_dir = 'datasets/catsvdogs_small'
os.mkdir(base_dir)

# Directories for the training, validation, and test splits

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'valid')
os.mkdir(validation_dir)
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
os.mkdir(test_dir)

# Directory with training cat pictures

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)

# Directory with training dog pictures 

train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(train_dogs_dir)

# Directory with validation cat pictures 

validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(validation_cats_dir)

# Directory with validation dog pictures

validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(validation_dogs_dir)

# Directory with test cat pictures

test_cats_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(test_cats_dir)

# Directory with test dog pictures

test_dogs_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(test_dogs_dir)

# Copying the first 1000 cat images to train_cats_dir

fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dir + 'train', fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

# Copying the next 500 cat images to validation_cats_dir

fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000, 1500)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(validation_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

# Copying the next 500 cat images to test_cats_dir

fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1500, 2000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(test_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

# Copying the first 1000 dog images to train_dogs_dir

fnames = ['dog.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

# Copying the next 500 dog images to validation_dogs_dir

fnames = ['dog.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000, 1500)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(validation_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

# Copying the next 500 dog images to test_dogs_dir 

fnames = ['dog.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1500, 2000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(test_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)


# Checking Images

print('Total train cat: ', len(os.listdir(train_cats_dir)))
print('Total train dog: ', len(os.listdir(train_dogs_dir)))
print('Total validation cat: ', len(os.listdir(validation_cats_dir)))
print('Total validation dog: ', len(os.listdir(validation_dogs_dir)))
print('Total test cat: ', len(os.listdir(test_cats_dir)))
print('Total test dog: ', len(os.listdir(test_dogs_dir)))
```

Error:

```
File "catsdogs.py", line 58, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Users\Leaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets/catsready exists: 'datasets/vdogstrain\\cat.0.jpg'
```

I want to know why does it search for the image using '\'. The images are all there I just can't figure out how to access them using os. By the looks of the error it stops on my first for loop for moving a part of the images to the other folder.

Comment: You should use `os.path.join()` to create `original_dir` and `base_dir` instead of hard coding a `'/'` in these two paths.

Comment: This might not fix the problem. To figure out what is wrong with your code, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice better yet, use `pathlib.Path` objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just tried both ways. Doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @binary0011 Please read the link about debugging that I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: since it's a windows system \\ should be ok. original_dir = 'datasets/catsvdogs'. it seems like 'cats' in original_dir got removed by the time the error occurred. 'datasets/vdogstrain\\cat.0.jpg'